# Do I need to use the DRF if I want to handle Token Authentication?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt

currently I plan on using AWS Cognito to handle my authentication for users. I want to do a simple registration and login.

So far, I have created a function which calls cognito's `initiate_auth` method. Currently my flow works like this:

User goes to `/signup`

After filling the form, I create a new user in the cognito backend and send them a verification mail

User is redirected to the `/login` page

The login function in the backend calls `initiate_auth` with the username and password, and retrieves some token information like this

```
{'AccessToken': '***', 'ExpiresIn': 3600, 'TokenType': 'Bearer', 'RefreshToken': '***', 'IdToken': '***'}
```

I believe these tokens are in the `JWT` format. My question now is, what exactly do I do with this? I know that I need to store this data, securely, somewhere, but I'm not sure what the best practice is.

I've heard that these tokens/data need to be saved in cookies in order to access them properly, but I also heard that there are some encryption problems, which is why I was looking for a library which handles this for me. I've come across this library: https://github.com/SimpleJWT/django-rest-framework-simplejwt

However, it seems like in order to use this library, I need to be using the DRF. However, my app is currently not the server handling/issuing out the tokens - it just retrieves them from Amazon. Do I need to convert these tokens for my application in some way?

Let's say I did have to use the DRF - then do I need to wrap the token handling functionality in it? I really don't know where to go from here. I am assuming that my authentication functions should be part of an API anyway, since, if I want to expand to a mobile version of the app, I can simply call the authentication function from my API. But I suspect that this would be a different step...and maybe I can kill two birds with one stone here.

Comment: Normally in Django Rest Framework, once the token is returned, we capture the token and save in our local storage using Javascript like this localStorage.setItem('authToken', token); And when we want to access the token again later to perform any actions which require authentication, we get the token using localStorage.getItem('authToken') and set it as a header in our network request.

Comment: got it, so you mean to use a cookie or a session?